# Track package version change in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, deb

Is there a way to track an event of a particular package update in Ubuntu and execute some script? In other words I want to execute a script when the installed package version is changed.

Comment: Maybe a trigger is what you need, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276535/dpkg-how-to-use-trigger

Comment: Thank you, seems like it might work for me!